# How do I add a Sprint using the Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Within the Azure DevOps Rest API I want to be able to add a Sprint programmatically.

I'm having trouble understanding how to accomplish this because it seems the documentation states I needed `id` before I can add at iteration.

Can someone please help me to understand what request I need to compose to create a new iteration via the API?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` that you need to provide in the body is the Classification Node Identifier, you can fetch the list from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/classification%20nodes/get) API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/{stractureGroup}/{path}?api-version=5.1
```

The `structreGroup` is `Areas` or `Iterations` (in your case it should be `Iterations`).

In the response you will get a `identifier` property with a GUID, use this GUID for the `id` in the create iteration API.