# How do I create a Sprint in Azure DevOps via the Python SDK?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Related to [How do I add a Sprint using the Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479222/how-do-i-add-a-sprint-using-the-rest-api) but more on the Python SDK

In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/post-team-iteration?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#examples it shows how to associate an Iteration to the team via an ID, but I can't seem to find the API to create the Iteration itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my script that would generate 2-week sprints for the 2024 year under the  `project_name` project and `team_name` team.  In addition because the SDK isn't type-safe I used `typing.cast` to ensure type safety.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
import azure.devops.exceptions
from azure.devops.v7_0.work.models import (
    TeamSettingsIteration,
    TeamContext,
)
from azure.devops.v7_0.work import WorkClient
from azure.devops.v7_0.work_item_tracking.models import WorkItemClassificationNode
from azure.devops.v7_0.work_item_tracking import WorkItemTrackingClient
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from typing import cast

organization_url = "https://dev.azure.com/..."
personal_access_token = "..."
project_name = "..."
team_name = "..."

start_date = datetime.strptime("2024-01-13", "%Y-%m-%d").astimezone(timezone.utc)
end_date = datetime.strptime("2024-12-31", "%Y-%m-%d").astimezone(timezone.utc)

credentials = BasicAuthentication("", personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

work_client = cast(WorkClient, connection.clients.get_work_client())
work_item_tracking_client = cast(
    WorkItemTrackingClient, connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()
)

current_date = start_date
while current_date + timedelta(days=13) <= end_date:
    iteration_end_date = current_date + timedelta(days=13)
    iteration_name = f"Sprint {iteration_end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"
    try:
        posted_node = WorkItemClassificationNode(
            name=iteration_name,
            attributes={
                "startDate": current_date,
                "finishDate": iteration_end_date,
            },
        )

        sprint_classifcation_node = cast(
            WorkItemClassificationNode,
            work_item_tracking_client.create_or_update_classification_node(
                posted_node=posted_node,
                project=project_name,
                structure_group="Iterations",
                path="Sprints\\2024",
            ),
        )
        iteration = TeamSettingsIteration(id=sprint_classifcation_node.identifier)
        team_context = TeamContext(project=project_name, team=team_name)
        team_iteration = cast(
            TeamSettingsIteration,
            work_client.post_team_iteration(
                iteration=iteration, team_context=team_context
            ),
        )

    except azure.devops.exceptions.AzureDevOpsServiceError as e:
        print(f"Failed to create iteration: {iteration_name}. Error: {e}")

    current_date += timedelta(weeks=2)
```